# Firebase DebugView mode Doesn't show any device

Tags: firebase, debugging, adb, firebase-analytics

I'm trying to debug an application and I've used debug view before on a different app.
However no devices show for this app while it shows on the other app how can that happen?

I did the following.

Open the terminal. and entered a command.

```
cd C:\Android\platform-tools
adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app com.example.myapp
```

start the app(com.example.myapp).
Check [Firebase -> Analytics -> DebugVIew]

For one app it shows my devices for the other it does not show.
What can I do to fix this???

Answer (score 11):

There are possible reasons why you’re unable to see the test devices on the DebugView console. I suggest you start from a newly installed app and make sure that no other app is running on debug mode, see below:

1. Uninstall the app from the device and install again.
2. Disable debug mode. This will ensure that no app is currently running under debug mode.

   ```
   adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app .none.
   ```
3. Enable verbose logging. This will help you immediately verify that events logged by the app are being sent or uploaded.

   ```
   adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE
   adb shell setprop log.tag.FA-SVC VERBOSE
   adb logcat -v time -s FA FA-SVC
   ```
4. Enable debug mode. Make sure that the package name is correct and same with what you defined in the gradle file.

   ```
   adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app <PACKAGE_NAME>
   ```
5. Log events. Aside from the events and properties automatically collected when the app starts or launches, you may also want to log custom events. After doing this, try putting the app in the background state and after some seconds to foreground state. This will trigger and help the SDK to upload the batched analytics data to server. Try checking the verbose logs for any errors or connectivity issues.
6. Wait. There is a delay before the DebugView can detect the debug device and show the analytics data.

Lastly, there are some reports before that different date and time settings of the debug device and your PC will cause this issue.

If this will not work on your case, you may reach out to the Firebase support team by filing a [bug report](https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/report/bugs).

Comment: I had debug mode working on a couple occasions, but it's a pain in the ass to get it to work... your method did not solve it this time, unfortunately